# How to iterate tuples passed as *args to a class method?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out why I cannot iterate through the elements of a tuple when passed into a class method as an `*args`.  I am using python 3.9.

The code works as expected when calling a method not part of a class.  When I run the following code:

```
class TestClass():

    def addition(*args):
        result = 0
        for arg in args:
            result += arg
        return result

def addition(*args):
    result = 0
    for arg in args:
        result += arg
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sum = addition(2, 5, 1, 9)
    print(sum)
    
    obj = TestClass()
    sum = obj.addition(2, 5, 1, 9)
    print(sum)
```

The first call to `addition()` yields 17 as expected.

However, the `obj.addition()` call throws the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
 unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'TestClass'
  File "C:\dev\sae\gitlab-metrics\test.py", line 8, in addition
    result += arg
  File "C:\dev\sae\gitlab-metrics\test.py", line 24, in <module>
    sum = obj.addition(2, 5, 1, 9)
```

If I check the type:

```
print(type(args))
```

indicates that both `args` variables are of type `tuple`.

What's interesting is when I examined the value of `arg` in the first pass of the loop, it's value is:`<__main__.TestClass object at 0x00000206F2CFC6A0>`

This just happens to be the same address as `args`.

It's like the for loop is passing an address to args instead of the number 2.  So I understand why the operand doesn't work.  But it is a complete mystery to me how to get to `args` as a tuple so I can iterate through.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're overlooking the implicit self argument. Calling `obj.addition(2, 5, 1, 9)` is the same as calling `TestClass.addition(obj, 2, 5, 1, 9)`. See where the problem is?

Comment: Because the first positional argument passed to a method is the instance itself. This is a basic part of writing Python class definitions. I suggest you check out the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) to familiarize yourself with these concepts

Comment: [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a class method, [the first argument](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) passed in implicitly is the instance of the object itself (usually the first argument is called `self`).

You either need to add another argument, e.g.:

```py
class TestClass():

    def addition(self, *args):
        result = 0
        for arg in args:
            result += arg
        return result
```

or make the method a [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod):

```py
class TestClass():

    @staticmethod
    def addition(*args):
        result = 0
        for arg in args:
            result += arg
        return result
```

Comment: Doh!  I forgot about `self`.  That makes perfect sense.   The `staticmethod` is a nice trick to add my toolbox.  Thanks @p34p5.

Comment: You're welcome! Would appreciate an up-vote

Comment: I long for the day when I have the privilege of up-voting ;-)